# Can a via go in the middle of a trace?

Tags: pcb, via

Is it a bad practice for any reason to put a via in the middle of a trace? For example, in terms of impedance, or reflection?

I have a power trace which I need to get across a bunch of signal traces by hopping to the other layer, and I'm wondering whether it would be best to put the via in the middle of the trace, like this:

[image]

Or if I should attach it using another trace, like this:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't do it on a transmission line, but I can't see any reason not to on a power rail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VIA in trace is OK unless you are designed for high speed signals or very high current.  The change in impedance and capacitance can cause signal integrity issues, reflections, for high speed signals.  Also keep in mind if the trace is carrying a lot of current, as the size of the "donut" can affect the amount of current flow (resistance change, temperature rise).

Comment: So you suggest the 2nd setup (where the donut is not interrupting the power line)?

Comment: Only if the trace is high speed or high current.  It's a wide trace and has a net of 3V3 so it's most likely a 3.3V rail  I can't tell what the size of anything based on the image (looks like Altium layout) so the safe method would be the second setup.  But I would clean up the blue (bottom) trace to come out of the via from the middle, not on the side.  See the [Saturn PCB toolkit](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit.htm) for trace and via modelers.

Answer (score 7):

Having a via in the middle of a trace is just fine in just about all situations except high-frequency RF stuff.  Your top photo is just fine.

Comment: Why is it bad for traces carrying HF signals? Is it because it changes the line impedance?

Comment: @Nate: Indeed -- it'd be an impedance bump.